# How to make WSL Ubuntu 1804 understand that WSL is enabled in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I try to install WSL on Windows 10, and since I don't have Microsoft Store in it, I try to install WSL via [URL](https://aka.ms/wsl-ubuntu-1804). I tried to use [this manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual), and I've got a problem.

Firstly, what's odd, when I try to download .appx file from the [URL](https://aka.ms/wsl-ubuntu-1804), I actually download .zip file. Then I extract it to desktop and try to run ubuntu.exe (having Windows Subsystem for Linux enabled in settings). I receive an error `The Windows Subsystem for Linux optional component is not enabled. Please enable it and try again. See https://aka.ms/wslinstall for details`.

What am I doing wrong? It would be very helpful for me if anybody helped me with this problem.

Comment: Did you enable wsl before trying to install Ubuntu as explained in the "See" link in the error message?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, as I've said, I enabled WSL in OptionalFeatures.exe before running ubuntu.exe, though after downloading a package with Ubuntu distro.

Answer (score 0):

Before being able to use WSL you need to enable the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" optional feature. You can enable it by running:

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
```

More installation instructions can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).